# How to prevent update operation only in child table in hibernate (one-to-many mapping unidirectional)?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables Restaurant and FoodItems.

My requirement:

1. If I added Restaurant data, then FoodItems data need to be added.
2. If I deleted Restaurant data, then FoodItems data need to be deleted.
3. If I updated Restaurant data, then FoodItems data need not to be updated.

Problems faced:
When I updated the restaurant details, then fooditems data is also updated.

Steps to reproduce :
I use postman tool to send JSON data to java side.
JSON :

{
"restaurantId": 1,
"restaurantName": "Salem RRR",
"restaurantAddress": "omr,chennai"
}

I don't pass the foodItems in the JSON. When I directly call session.update(restaurant) in java side,
then fooditems data is deleted.
I know it is because of cascade = CascadeType.ALL option in restaurant table.

My Query :
But I don't know how to prevent the update operation.
I am new to hibernate. please help us to get rid of this problem.
Thanks in advance

Restaurant.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Column(name = "restaurant_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int restaurantId;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_name",nullable = false)
    private String restaurantName;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_address",nullable = false)
    private String restaurantAddress;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "restaurant_fooditems",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id",referencedColumnName = "restaurant_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="food_id",referencedColumnName = "food_id")})
    private Set<FoodItems> foodItems;

}
```

FoodItems.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "fooditems")
public class FoodItems {

    @Column(name = "food_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int foodId;

    @Column(name = "food_name",nullable = false)
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "price",nullable = false)
    private double price;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know it is because of cascade = CascadeType.ALL option in restaurant table.

Well, not exactly. It's because `Restaurant` is the owner of the association between itself and the `FoodItem`s. This means the association state is controlled by the `Restaurant.foodItems` property.

Assuming that you are simply calling `restaurantRepository.save(restaurant)` in your service method, then if `Restaurant.foodItems` is empty, all previous `foodItem`s are assumed to be removed from the association. The problem will persist even without `CascadeType.ALL`.

The simplest solution would be to load the original `Restaurant` from the data store, and only copy over the fields you want updated - sth like:

```
@Transactional
public void update(Restaurant updated) {
    restaurantRepository.findById(updated.getId())
        .ifPresent(original -> {
            original.setRestaurantName(updated.getRestaurantName());
            original.setRestaurantAddress(updated.getRestaurantAddress());
        });
}
```